# On the local inextensibility of the Kruskal solution

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime

It is stated that Kruskal extension is the unique analytic and locally inextendible extension of the Schwarzschild solution (Hawking, Ellis "The Large Structure of Space-time" p.153). **How can it be proven that doesn't exist such extension?**

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time.